# hadoop single node setup bash: bin/hadoop permission denied

Tags: hadoop

I have an error when trying to setup a single node hadoop cluster at the step of 
formatting namenode.

The command:

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

The error:

```
bash: bin/hadoop : permission denied
```

I tried this on ubuntu 12.10, 12.04, 11.04 and got the same error for all.

What can I do?

Comment: what directory are you doing this from? bin/hadoop is a relative directory.

Comment: installation directory 
/home/hduser/hadoop/

complete command : 
hduser@ubutu:/hadoop$ bin/hadoop namenode -format

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l bin/hadoop`?  The file is probably not owned by hduser.  Did you unpack/install Hadoop as root?

Comment: @Matt D _> thank you Matt you had pointed me to the solution ... it was missing execute permission for files in bin/hadoop directory and it's now working after providing execute permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the permissions of your HADOOP_HOME. for a detailed help you can visit this [link](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-configure-hadoop.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions of hadoop script:

```
do ls -l ./bin/hadoop
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot all,,

it was missing execute permission for files in bin/hadoop directory and it's now working after providing execute permission using chmod command

Comment: and how is it different from my answer??

Comment: the same idea but just need to mention the type of permission needed...which is execute  and to change it using chmod command

but at all, all answers are welcome , true and helpful for me thanks alot